# Path in node with parameter passed is not found

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to `get` a page with `express-router` when inside of the `url` `:id` is supplied as a parameter using `passport` custom callback and the `url` is somehow not found. Here is what I have in the main file:

```
var app = express();
var index = require('./routes/index');

app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
    console.log('passport callback');
    console.log(err);
    console.log(info);
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.status(401).json(info); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      console.log('logIn function of /login path');
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/auth/' + user.local.username + '/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
  console.log('end of login function');
});
app.use('/auth/:id/', passport.authenticate(['facebook-token', 'local-signup']), index);
```

And inside the `index` I have:

```
router.get('/auth/:id/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("router of index.js is sending app.html");
  var appPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'app.html');
  res.sendFile(appPath);
});
```

I see the redirect to `/auth/nik1989/` happening, but the `url` is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from [Express 4.x API - Router](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router)

```
// will handle any request that ends in /events
// depends on where the router is "use()'d"
router.get('/events', function(req, res, next) {
  // ..
});

// only requests to /calendar/* will be sent to our "router"
app.use('/calendar', router);
```

Following the example to call `events` end point you have to do `/calendar/events`.

Now in your case the way you inject the middleware clearly **wrong**

```
router.get('/auth/:id/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("router of index.js is sending app.html");
  var appPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'app.html');
  res.sendFile(appPath);
});

app.use('/auth/:id/', passport.authenticate(['facebook-token', 'local-signup']), index);
```

cause the url that you have to call is `/auth/:id/auth/:id/`.

If you breakdown above code what you are doing is somethink like this

```
app.use('/auth/:id/',passport..., router.get('/auth/:id/'...)
```

There are many ways to fix it I have put some examples below.

**Examples**

**Working example one**

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  console.log("router of index.js is sending app.html");
  var appPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'app.html');
  res.sendFile(appPath);
});

app.use('/auth', passport.authenticate(['facebook-token', 'local-signup']), index);
```

**Working example two**

```
router.get('/auth/:id', function(req, res) {
  console.log("router of index.js is sending app.html");
  var appPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'app.html');
  res.sendFile(appPath);
});

app.use(passport.authenticate(['facebook-token', 'local-signup']), index);
```

Comment: I understand what you are talking about, tried all of the examples of how to fix it, but neither of them worked (    I am wondering whether the fact that I am using `https` matters here

Comment: I asked a separate question regarding further fixes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337431/cant-render-html-with-express-router-and-passport-bad-request-or-not-found-err

Answer (score 1):

This should the cause

```
app.use('/auth/:id/', passport.authenticate(['facebook-token', 'local- 
signup']), index);
```

you already have a route in your index.js file thats has the same url structure
  `/auth/:id/`

when you use app.use('/account', accoutRouter);
it means every other route called by his app .use middleware will have 
account/ prepend to it e.g account/login, account/register 

i didn't see passport initialization in your code

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());
```

but i believe  using

```
router.get('/auth/:id/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("router of index.js is sending app.html");
  var appPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'app.html');
  res.sendFile(appPath);
});
```

and

```
app.use('/auth/:id/', passport.authenticate(['facebook-token', 'local- 
signup']), index);
```

will definitely cause errors